# How to correctly install Compiz on Xfce 4?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, compiz, xfce, compositing

As I understand, Compiz can be installed as the compositing-manager on various desktop environments. I am using Ubuntu Studio 15.10 with Xfce 4.12 and I want to install Compiz in its basic configuration just to use simple fading, shadows and maybe the infamous Cube workspace-switcher, however I would like the visuals of my windows to stay as they are.

So far, I have only found old tutorials on how to install Compiz on Xfce that are sometimes dated multiple years back and often involve adding additional PPAs or plugins and applications that I do not want to use or can not understand the use of.

Is it possible to just install and use the Compiz version from the Ubuntu Software Center to get what I am looking for? Or will I still need some additional software to make it compatible to Xfce?

It would be great if someone could explain a current way of installing just the basic Compiz functionality or point to an up-to-date website which explains this.

---

[Edit]: I tried the installation myself and found out what is necessary to set up in the process. If you need a guide, please refer to the answer I posted blow.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install compiz` should install it. You may also want to install `compizconfig-settings-manager`. It short, the answer is yes to all the questions, though I am not sure what you want explained, and what is "make it compatible to XFCE 4.12".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer this question for someone who is looking for the same explanation as myself:

When installing Compiz just by itself, it will use its own built-in `gtk-window-decorator`, meaning that the window title bars will vanish on the first start without further configuration and if enabling the window decoration, the default blue theme will be used.

I would advise to install/configure it in the following way without any additional PPAs or external window decorators:

1. Start by deactivating any compositors: In the Xfce options by unticking "compositing" in the window management settings or, if installed, by removing custom compositors such as Compton from the startup applications.
2. Open a terminal and enter: `sudo apt install compiz compiz-plugins compizconfig-settings-manager dconf-editor` (The Compiz-Plugins are also needed for additional functionality such as animations and the Cube, dconf-editor for setting up the original Xfce Greybird-theme or another installed theme.)
3. Press `Alt+F2` and enter `dconf-editor` to open it, then change the "theme"-value to your theme, e.g. `Greybird` in `org\gnome\desktop\wm\preferences`.
   You may also look for the "button-layout" value and move the window buttons to either side here. The value works as such `left-button1,left-button2:right-button1,right-button2`. So by simply entering the button names (minimize, maximize, close), the window buttons will be situated to either side in order, seperated by a comma.
4. Open the CompizConfig Settings Manager from the regular Xfce-settings menu under Extras and at least enable the following plugins: `Composite, OpenGL, Window Decoration, Move Window, Resize Window, Place Windows`. (You may also want to add such things as `Grid` for tiling windows and `Application Switcher` for alt-tabbing windows and so on.) Also make sure that four horizontal workspaces are enabled in the general settings when wanting to use the Cube plugin. To find out what plugins I could/should enable, I used the following sources: [How To Set Up Compiz In Xubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/how-to-set-up-compiz-in-xubuntu-1210-or.html), [Compiz Fusion on Your Desktop: Howto Ubuntu (Video Series)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFqj2hS_0iQ), [Xubuntu + Compiz = Pretty pretty Xubuntu](https://xubuntublog.wordpress.com/2007/12/09/xubuntu-compiz-pretty-pretty-xubuntu/)
5. Press `Alt+F2` again and enter `compiz --replace` to find out if everything works correctly before adding it to the Autostart Applications or changing any statup system files. If there are any problems, a simple logout/reboot will deactivate it again.
6. You may have to use the command `bash -c "sleep 2; compiz --replace"` in the Autostart Applications, in case it doesn't start with `compiz --replace` alone.

---

[Edit] A few fixes, if you should need them:

- If you situate a panel with the Whisker Menu at the bottom (Windows-like look), the menu will pop up a few pixels too high when using the `Place Windows` plugin. Just add a rule in the plugin settings for a fixed window placement for `title=Whisker Menu` and simply leave all settings on default.
- When using newer GTK+ 3 programs like Gedit or GNOME Disks, Compiz will sometimes draw the window frame incorrectly (square, with space around it). This can be fixed by installing `gtk3-nocsd` from the official repository and rebooting to force traditional window styling.

Comment: Just a hint that may help,  you may get rid of dconf dependency as it's not used in xfce by setting backend to `ini` in `/etc/compizconfig/config`, then it will use flat-file. Also you may create a profile dedicated to xubuntu-session. You can make same setup from ccsm > preferences.

Comment: What is the relevant startup file in bionic? The compositor is no longer specified in xfce4-session.xml

Comment: @sawablo, What startup file are you looking for in which DE? On Xfce/Xubuntu, you just have to disable (untick) the compositor in the system settings and add the startup command from step 7 manually, also in the system settings at 'startup applications'.

Comment: @Prototype700 thanks, I think that's what I did. Using GNOME on Pop!_OS now.

Comment: Had the same issue with Ubuntu Studio 18.04.  This answer combined with unlocking the dpkg directory solved it (https://www.tecmint.com/fix-unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-lock/).