# How to add shadow to the Xfce4 panel using Compiz?

Tags: compiz, xfce, panel, xfce-panel, shadow

I'm using Xfce4 currently with Compiz, which I installed following [my own workflow here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702858/how-to-correctly-install-compiz-on-xfce-4-12/703509#703509).

After some changes to my desktop setup, I would like to add a shadow to the Xfce panel, but I've been unsuccessful so far.

Compiz is active and I can even change the shadow effects live in CCSM under Window Decorations. Adding and removing specific windows from both the decoration and the shadow effects also works, but even though both values are set to `any` and even when I specifically add `| class=Xfce4-panel` to them, the panel won't draw a shadow.

The command is specified as `/usr/bin/gtk-window-decorator`, even though I have installed Metacity for window decorations, but it appears to work this way, so I am not sure if that is correct or not.

I believe that there should be a rule somewhere that prevents shadows from being drawn by panels and such things as Firefox bookmark-popups. I remember that there was an option to specify this in Compton, but I don't know where to find it for Compiz or any other way to accomplish this.

Is there a way to add a shadow to the Xfce panel?