# Compiz in Ububtu Studio

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, compiz, xfce, mac

I'm trying to setup up compiz in Ububtu Studio 18.04 on a dual boot mac (specs below)  I installed compiz:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz*
```

Seemed to work and the settings manager is there.  Then I disabled the default compositor by unticking Enable Display Compositing (Settings Manager > Window Manager Tweaks > Compositor).  I run compiz:

```
compiz --replace
```

It seems to crash before if finishes and window elements disappear.  Compiz seems to work as the window movement warping works.  I added compiz to (Settings Manager > Session and Startup > Application Autostart) and restarted.  Still no window elements and now compiz doesn't work.

Any ideas as to what the issue might be or what I could try?

--

Mac Mini mid 2010, 2.4Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo Nvidia GeForce 320m 256mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here - [How to correctly install Compiz on Xfce 4.12?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702858/how-to-correctly-install-compiz-on-xfce-4-12) in combination with unlocking the dpkg directory (https://www.tecmint.com/fix-unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-lock/) solved this for me if anyone is having the same issue.